# Order of evaluation in Spring bean definition dsl for kotlin?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-bean-dsl

I wonder when `environment` method is being taken into account.

Considering following code:

```
bean { Bar(ref()) } // requires bean of type Foo
environment(
    { !activeProfiles.contains("local") },
    { ProdFoo() }))
environment(
    { activeProfiles.contains("local") },
    { bean<LocalFoo>() })
```

Sometimes I observed errors related with no bean of type `Foo`. Does it mean that `environment` is not evaluated as one of the first expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is plain simple - I've forgot to wrap `ProdFoo()` into `bean{ ... }`